# Windows 10 Professional, Macbook Air , cirrus logic on Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bootcamp, windows

I have Windows 10 Professional installed on my Macbook Air.
I am using bootcamp version 6.0

I have serious issue with my audio device:

**Scenario 1**:

When my headphones are plugged in and i play a move via VLC player. if i pause the movie go away, then comeback after awhile and try to resume (play) the movie, i hear no sound and i see a red 'X' on my audio task bar icon.

**Scenario 2**:

My macbook air laptop is plugged to a Dell monitor (external view). my headphones are plugged in. they work and after a while they stop working and i see the audio device has switched to my dell monitor.

**Something I've noticed:**

If i click the audio taskbar icon to get the volume slide, if its color is orange then i will get the issues described above, if its color is blue then this issue doesn't occur. I wonder if there is connection

This is very annoying and it would be so much appreciated if someone has encountered this issue and knows how to help me

Comment: Can you expand on your details?  How is your headphone connected; via the 3.5mm audio jack or through USB?  How is the Dell Monitor connected?  Do you have any USB connections to the monitor?  If you don't pause, does the problem present?  What about using another media player?  Does it present there?

Answer (score 1):

quick update:
* The color of the slider volume control has nothing to do with this issue. it just represent the current theme win 10 is using

- I've downloaded cirrus logic driver CS4208(AB 126) and so far so good...i will update it that didn't work

Comment: Would have been great if you had posted the link to download **cirrus logic driver CS4208(AB 126)** I am looking for these drivers and couldnt find it. I have no sound in my Mac with windows 10 Pro. Thanks